# How to use ssh to copy a file multiple hops with agent forwarding?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, ssh-agent

I have a group of servers all properly configured with SSH agent forwarding. It is a typical bastion server style configuration where the only machine you can connect to from the outside is server A. From server A you can use agent forwarding to connect to servers B, C, D, etc. It is all working perfectly.

Sometimes I want to copy a file from my local machine to server B. In order to do this I have to first scp the file to server A. Then ssh to server A and scp the file to server B. Then I delete the file from server A.

Is there a way to copy the file directly from my computer to server B via server A in just one command executed on my local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your sshd is configured to allow TCP forwarding then you can set up a tunnel from your computer to B via A and then use it to copy things through. Create the tunnel

```
ssh -f -L 2050:B:22 A -N
```

- `-f` background the ssh command so you get your terminal back to use.
- `-L 2050:B22` bind localhost port 2050 to host B port 22
- `-N` do not execute a remote command.

then to copy from your computer to B

```
scp -P 2050 filetocopy localhost:/destination/path
```

EDIT:
If you use

```
ssh -L 2050:B:22 A -N &
```

Then you will be told the PID of the ssh command when it backgrounds.

Comment: how do I close the tunnel afterwards?

Comment: You would have to use `ps` to identify the PID of the ssh command that is doing the tunnelling. Alternatively see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Put something like this into .ssh/config:

```
Host B-p C-p D-p
        ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p A.example.com
Host B-p
        Hostname B.example.com
Host C-p
        Hostname C.example.com
Host D-p
        Hostname D.example.com
```

and just ssh or scp to/from `B-p`. You can omit the `-p` suffix and configure the ProxyCommand directly on the `B.example.com` etc. if you are always "outside".

This incurs a little traffic overhead between your machine and the bastion host, but works without agent forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar (even more complex) case recently and managed to solve the problem.

The short answer: use `ProxyCommand` instead of agent forwarding.

The long story:

In my case four hosts are involved:

- Linux desktop in my office
- Linux VPN server somewhere on the Internet
- Linux home server in my apartment
- Linux laptop in my apartment

The router in my apartment gets no public address from the ISP, so home laptop and home servers are both behind double-NAT, no way I can do port forwarding or something because I cannot control ISP devices. For some reason, the home server is always connected to a VPN server with public address. This way I can `ssh -A` into the VPN server, and `ssh -A` into home server and finally `ssh` into my home laptop.

But sometimes I need to transfer files. I do not want to `rsync` / `scp` multiple times hop by hop.

`ProxyCommand` comes to rescue. Put these in the `~/.ssh/ssh_config`:

```
# Host A is a VPN gateway with public address.
Host a.example.org
  HostName 1.2.3.4

# Host B is a home server / gateway with no public address.
# It's connected to host A via VPN.
Host b.example.org
  HostName 10.255.255.100
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p a.example.org

# Host C is my home laptop.
Host c.example.org
  HostName 192.168.2.100
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p b.example.org

# vim: ft=sshconfig:
```

This could be indefinitely chained. You can keep chaining host D, host E, etc as long as your hosts have fast connections. There is no need to do `ssh -L` or `ssh -D` hop by hop manually and connect through non-standard ports. I can now do `ssh c.example.org` directly from anywhere as long as I can connect to `a.example.org`. Of course other SSH-based protocols like Rsync, SCP, SFTP, etc are automatically supported.

Answer (score 0):

You might use tar to copy the file:

```
tar cC SRC-DIR SRC-FILE | ssh A.example.com ssh B.example.com tar xC DST-DIR
```

Be sure to add the correct amount of quoting to DST-DIR if required; it will be interpreted by three shells.

Using ssh and tar is very flexible, for example when scp refuses to work with two remote locations.

Comment: I want to do this but without a real example I can copy and paste I'm going to give up experimenting with all the escaping.